# Number+number="numbernumber" in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, textbox, numbers

I get 050 if I type 50 to the textbox and have 0 as the offsetTop. Why? This is the code:

```
alert(allspan[i].offsetTop+document.getElementById("size").value);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The return type of `.value` is a string, so you get string concatenation instead of two numbers being added.

You need to use `parseInt` on the value.

```
alert(allspan[i].offsetTop + parseInt(document.getElementById("size").value,10));
```

Comment: @Christoph "if it is a string with letters mixed in, you will get NaN as result." more bulletproof is always better :)

Comment: @jbabey if this case happens, it is most likely that an error occured (wrong input from the user) and i would rather like to intercept that (test for NaN) than silently get a wrong result:-p

Answer (score 1):

You probable need to use `parseInt(myVar)` or `parseFloat(myVar)` to convert it to a numeric datatype.

Comment: @Oded agreed, though it defaults to different radixes(radii?) depending on what the string begins with.

Comment: @Oded not true, the default is `10` for any leading number except `0` or `0x`

Comment: @Christoph - Yes, I did not get it completely right. But that doesn't change the fact that you should always use the radix.

Answer (score 1):

Your adding an integer `(allspan[i].offsetTop)` to a string(`document.getElementById("size").value`) which will be a string.

If you make the second value an integer you will be fine:

```
allspan[i].offsetTop + parseInt(document.getElementById("size").value)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem. If you are going to be using a variable in a mathematical equation then you have to make sure it is a number by using `parseInt(variableName)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
alert(parseInt(allspan[i].offsetTop) + parseInt(document.getElementById("size").value));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because `document.getElementById("size").value` is returning a string, not an integer. Try this:

```
parseInt(document.getElementById("size").value);
```